# Memory layout inheritance

Tags: c++, visual-c++, gcc, compatibility, abi

Consider the following two structs:

```
struct A
{
    // A bunch of standard layout data
};

struct B:public A
{
    // Other data
};
```

And an object

```
B foo;
```

Supposing sizeof(A) does not differ between the compilers, the packing is the same and B does not add any virtual methods, will foo have the A members at the same address relative to &foo when compiling using gcc or msvc for the Windows x86 or x86-64 platform?

EDIT: I relized that the best way to implement inheritance is to place A before B. Otherwise, upcast would require offseting the this pointer by sizeof(B) which is silly. At least GCC puts the content of B after the content of A.

Comment: no, even when using the same exe on the same computer, the bits can  move.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization.

Comment: Please edit the question to clarify if `foo` is in global scope, and why you think they will/wont have the same address.

Comment: OP doesn't ask, if foo will be in the same place in executable file, but if contents of B will be ordered the same way on different platforms. The order will be kept, but platform may influence padding (see #pragma pack)

Comment: @user - This sounds like an XY problem. You try to solve X by doing Y, and now you ask us if Y is going to work. Please tell us a bit about X as well. What are you going to use this for?

Comment: @BoPerrson Virtual calls accross dll boundaries. A will contain a *manually* constructed vtable where each entry points to a normal c function whose first argument is this. A will also contain non-virtual wrapper methods that uses the corresponding entry in the vtable.

Answer (score 2):

The x86_64 architecture is a problem, GCC and MSVC chose different memory models.  GCC is LP64, MSVC is LLP64.  In other words, the *long* type is 64-bits in GCC, 32-bits in MSVC.

"Same address" is pretty ambiguous in the question, but clearly you'll have a problem if A and B are not compiled by the same compiler.  In which case possibly different packing will be an issue as well.  Interpolating from that same ambiguity, if B contains any virtual members and A does not then the layout of A and B are not compatible.  B will have the v-table pointer inserted.

Comment: Considering it's a DLL, it would be reasonable to use only SDK types. `DWORD` is 4 bytes on any compiler targeting Windows, even for Windows on ARM. And given that the Win32 SDK relies on structure layouts, Win32 compilers do not have freedom to choose arbitrary packings.

Comment: @MSalters What about the order when inheriting. Can I be sure that members of A comes first or last?

Comment: @user877329: The SDK uses inheritance when compiling C++, but only for COM interfaces and those have no data members. You therefore can't deduce inheritance layout from that.

Comment: @MSalters: Remember the vtable pointer! Or how does COM work. Other black magic?

Comment: @user877329: That too; COM always assumes a vtable ptr and your `struct A` doesn't have one. Therefore any conclusions drawn from COM layouts doesn't apply to `A`.

Comment: @Hans Passant. MinGW is LLP64

Comment: @MSalters: In fact A *has* a vtable pointer. However, it is not added by the compiler but by myself. So A looks like
struct A
{
VtableForA* vt;
};
Where VtableForA is a struct consisting of function pointers pointing to functions in the loaded DLL.

Answer (score 1):

Hans has explained everything correctly. The general answer is NO. This will not work out of the box for any class/compiler, etc.

Nevertheless. C++ has features like `#pragma pack`, alignment record in the class, etc. All these stuffs are for generating required or predefined memory layout. If you will carefully use them (maybe with some `#ifdefs` also), you will have compatibility that you want. This was used in tons of projects and it worked.

But still you will have to carefully check layouts for every compiler that you use.